# Custom HTTP Methods for Ajax in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: jquery, python, django, google-app-engine, web-applications

So I was reading the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html) for the RequestHandler class in python, and I noticed that it supports several more methods other than the two that I'm used to, namely GET and POST.

Is it possible to add custom methods to the RequestHandler class or my class that implements RequestHandler to extend those methods even further?

For example, this would be a typical implementation of a webapp:

```
class MainPage (webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #do things
        self.response.out.write("This was get")
```

Could I also add a method like this?

```
    def SaveAttribute(self):
        #do more things
        self.response.out.write("Attribute saved")
```

I ask specifically so I can easily set up a jquery-ajax heavy app engine webapp, and if I could use custom methods like that with the "type" parameter in the .ajax() call it would make my life considerably easier than just handling everything through POST.

If this is not possible then is there a fairly straightforward way to do what I need to do?

Comment: webapp has the allowed methods hardcoded in. You might be able to do it with another framework or a customized version of webapp, but I haven't tried; I don't know if the runtime itself will pass on any random HTTP request or if it's restricted to the allowed types on a higher level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [ProtoRPC](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/overview.html) ... it's not exactly what you're asking, but achieves the same kind of end-result.

Comment: That falls under the "fairly straigtforward way to do what I need to do" part of my question. =)